# Facebook share button finished with blank page in Android webview

Tags: javascript, android, facebook, webview

When I open webview and click Facebook share, it works.
But when share is finished, it opens a blank page.

Sometimes, it doesn't open blank page and show origin page. but usually it opens blank page.

I want to show page that includes share button. always

Here is my code:

```
   //in onCreate.
    String Url = //my url//;
    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
    cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
    view = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    view.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    view.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    view.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    view.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    view.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    view.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(view, true);
    }

    view.loadUrl(Url);

    view.setWebViewClient(new myWebViewClient());
    view.setWebChromeClient(new ChromeClient());
    //

    private class ChromeClient extends WebChromeClient{

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {

        MainActivity.this.setProgress(newProgress*1000);
    }
    public void onCloseWindow(WebView window){
       super.onCloseWindow(window);
    }
```

And here is javascript code:

```
    function fn_facebook_share() {
    var url = //my url//;
    var title  = "${VideoModelDetail.title}";
    var user_nm= "${VideoModelDetail.user_nm}";
    var univ="${VideoModelDetail.univ_cd_nm}";

    FB.ui({
          method: 'feed',
          link: url,
          name:title,
          caption:univ+" | "+user_nm,
          description:'text',
        }, function(response){});
}
```

Comment: Can you provide screenshots, a link to your webpage, or some more information? Really hard to tell from this code if you actually initialized the SDK correctly. Why not just use the provided Social Plugins?

Comment: @SleepyPanda Thanks for your reply, but I've solved this problem just using another webview. This caused by webview use url not a javascript function but a link url. It opens url pop up in webview, not a facebook function. So I make an webview to handle when webview is using function as url.

Comment: Can you please share me the example code of how you're handling JS function for social sharing?

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your webview to xml layout file. The blank page error was caused due to js script fail while redirecting oAuth login to authorization acceptance page. You can overcome this issue by moving your webview into xml layout.I had the same issue on my android application. The cause of the issue is FB login javascript opens a new page on a new window

Comment: Can you please share me the example code of how you're handling JS function for social sharing?